# Disabling Visual Studio Code update notification

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I permanently disable this update notification?

[image]

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Go to File > Preferences >  Settings (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>)

Here two files will open. One is "Default Settings" and other is "User Settings".

Add a new parameter in "User Settings"

```
"update.mode": "none"
```

Then save the files, VS Code will ask you to restart, and then you won't receive the update message.

---

In GUI configuration, the setting will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Isn't this stopping the updates completely though? Is there a way to just disable the notification?

Comment: Yep, this isn't exactly what was asked. Updates are stopped.

Comment: For those running linux, after following this guide you can still get the updates delivered to you by following the guide here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux. This way, your package manager will still fetch and install the updates and you still get the benefit of not always getting notified by vscode of an update. This was what I needed

Comment: You can set `"update.channel": "manual"` to disable automatic updates.

Comment: This option is deprecated. Use `"update.mode": "none"` instead.

Comment: Are the extensions updates still working?

Answer (score 29):

For the latest versions of VS code (I am using version 1.32.2) the parameter `"update.channel": "none"` is deprecated. To disable updates use `"update.mode": "none"`

Comment: this is the right entry. The option in accepted answer is no longer available.

Comment: but it stops updating VSC completly including notification of course, the question is about to disable notifications and continue automatic updates which seem impossible at this point

Answer (score 6):

To date, we can't deactivate only the update notification. Either you stop update, or you deactivate all notifications. For the latter: go to settings (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) then add:

`"editor.parameterHints": false`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, doing that I still get the update notification

Answer (score 6):

Go in the settings with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>.

Then set `"update.mode"` to `"manual"`.

VS Code will no longer check for updates on its own, but you will still be able to update it when you want to, by clicking on the cog at the bottom left:

[image]

Comment: Firewall says it still tries to connect update.code.visualstudio.com in "manual" mode :-/ (at least in Version: 1.50.1)

Comment: @zxcat at least it stops showing the notification badge which can be annoying. You can probably open an issue at their github repo.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed VS Code through a package manager (apt/yum/snap...) it will handle the updates and you can turn them off in code: `Settings > Update: Mode > none`.