# Visual Studio Community 2017 Ver 15.8.6 - How to disable update notifications?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, auto-update

[image]

Found this thread
[Disabling Visual Studio Code update notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496935/disabling-visual-studio-code-update-notification)

But File > Preferences > Settings is not available in my VS.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823728/visual-studio-2017-tells-me-a-visual-studio-2019-version-is-now-available-every

Comment: Yes that notification is not appearing anymore after choose to install.

Comment: Unfortunately, the notification appear again on the next day...